# undefined property: user::$load Call to a member function model() on a non-object in

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried making a login function using CodeIgniter framework. But, I have this error.
And I have a construct in login controller class.
the error is "can't load Model"

[image]

Comment: Please add the code first.

Comment: its typo error.., `laod ` to `load`

Comment: I hope my answer helped you please accept it if did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have miss spelled

Change

```
laod
```

to

```
load
```

on line 21

Also rename your controller where the first letter is only upper case on class and file name as what user guide says

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming